# How did Catwoman manage to pierce Batman's armor using a sewing claw?

Tags: batman, catwoman, batman-returns

In *Batman Returns*, Batman's suit was effectively bullet-proof armor (as in the first movie *Batman* from 1989). How could the ordinary sewing claw Catwoman stabbed Batman with pierce it? The penetration energy of a bullet is much greater than any human thrust can achieve.

Comment: Good lord. I'd forgotten how terrible this film was.

Comment: Bullet proof materials are not necessarily stab, slash or pierce proof.

Comment: @Valorum I actually liked it though.

Comment: Trivia: kevlar, which is known to be effective against bullets, have poor level of protection against stabs, from what little I read.

Comment: @Clockwork - It's not that it's a badly *made* film, it's terrible in other ways. The lighting and camerawork are excellent, as is the sound quality.

Comment: It was pretty weird, but not as bad as the films that were to follow.

Comment: Holtzman effect - it stops fast-moving projectiles, but lets slow-moving blades through. Pretty sure I've seen that in some popular science documentary.

Comment: @Valorum I loved it back then. Michelle Pfeiffer is awesome as Catwoman and De Vito makes a creepy Penguin. It's campy, but not unwatchably campy as Schumacher's movies.

Comment: @AndresF. - it's not the *worst* Batman film.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Her claws went *between* the sheets of armour plating, where his torso plating meets his armoured trousers

> Her hand stopped at that point just above the waist where the two main
> pieces of his armor joined. Without warning, she drove her talons
> through the fabric into his flesh.
>
> <sub><sup>[Batman Returns - Official Novelisation](https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Batman_Returns_(Novelization))</sup></sub>

This mirrors the scene in the [screenplay](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/batman-returns_shooting.html).

> **CATWOMAN:** *Who are you?  Who's the man behind the bat?  Maybe he can help me find the woman behind the Cat.*
> (pressing armor)
> *That's not him ... Ah, here you are ...*
>
> Her talons poise at the edge of Batman's armor, just above
> the waist.  Suddenly Catwoman thrusts.  Batman ROARS with
> pain and fiercely swats Catwoman away -- off the building!

Answer (score -1):

As has been addressed in other Batman media, and is also accurate to real life, there are soft flexible spots between armour plating. There has to be, otherwise it would be impossible to move. In the scene, Catwoman specifically probes around his side to find a weak spot, which again makes sense because his suit would likely be designed with the armour plating on the front of his chest, and less so on the sides.

Also, as a sidenote, real life body armour is in fact often more vulnerable to stabs and cuts from blades. It's designed to absorb and distribute the kinetic impact of a bullet. Despite that force being much less than a blade thrust, a bullet is also much more blunt than a blade tip, which if sharp enough can penetrate between kevlar fibers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This says the same thing as the existing answer, without the evidence.  Please don't post duplicate answers.